# Trying to block ZmEu and Ezooms using htaccess mod-rewrite results in error 310 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, security

I'm trying to block the ZmEu and Ezooms abuse I've been getting. I tried following what was discussed in this link: http://www.philriesch.com/articles/2010/07/getting-a-little-sick-of-zmeu/ but my attempt results in Error 310, too many redirects. Any idea what's causing this loop?

My htaccess code is below. I temporarily set one of the HTTP_USER_AGENT values as Chrome to test it.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_base/special/ip-flagged
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (.*)Chrome(.*)|(.*)ZmEu(.*) 
RewriteRule .* /my_base/special/ip-flagged [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /my_base
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Adding the lines,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to the first RewriteRule stopped the loop. So now the following code always redirects to the "ip-flagged" page whenever the browser used is Chrome:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_base/special/ip-flagged
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (.*)Chrome(.*)
RewriteRule .* /my_base/special/ip-flagged [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /my_base
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```